# Should questions with accepted [extra tag] solutions be edited to include the [extra tag]?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

If a question is asked and the accepted answer to that question includes the use of another tag, should the question be edited to add the tag?

For example, a good amount of the CSS questions I answer use `flexbox` as a solution. If the answer is accepted as the correct answer, is it appropriate to edit the question to include the `flexbox` tag? My main concern for adding the tag is so that those who are searching for `flexbox` answers will be able to find them.

Here [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452977/navigation-fill-100-of-container/39453089#39453089) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712649/how-to-create-black-transparent-overlay-modal-dialog-with-centered-text-on-an-i/39712923#39712923) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577582/equal-space-margin-css/39577643#39577643) of my own answers that have used `flexbox` to solve non-flexbox questions.

Answer (score 2):

Doing that kind of weirds me out, although I do see it happen often.

The heuristic I prefer is to determine if the tags line up with the technologies that the OP is asking about.  In the examples you've linked, flexbox isn't mentioned, so in my mind, it's **not** safe to add the flexbox tag to them.

Worse, it may be counter-productive; we don't know if the OP has written this code to support older versions of Internet Explorer (and yes, those sort of devs still do exist).

Comment: I can definitely see your point. My main thought was what if someone was looking for flexbox solutions by searching the tag. If there was a flexbox answer to a CSS question that didn't reference the tag, they would never come across it.

Comment: @HunterTurner:  I'd prefer to think of it from the perspective of the OP on this one.  If I as an OP asked a JavaScript DOM manipulation *without* mentioning jQuery, yet I accepted an answer which had jQuery in it, it doesn't *automatically* imply that I'm asking a question which involves jQuery.  Adding the tag implies that I've been doing the whole thing "wrong" from a jQuery perspective.  Further, the checkmark only really means anything to the OP anyway and it shouldn't be used as a barometer of much else besides satisfying whatever the OP believes to be the answer.